# Auto Populate Parent Object field from child object

Tags: apex

is it possible to populate parent object field when child record is created without using triggers?
I have email id field in account object and there are multiple email address which are stored in custom object and added as child to account object.Whenever someone change the type of email address from public to private i need to update parent object accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely do this with `Process Builder`. When you get to the point where you are selecting your action choose `Update Records`. Then you can select `Records related to your Account` or whatever custom object you replace `Account` with. From the dropdown you can select a parent relationship.[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by using cross object field updates.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_cross_object_field_updates.htm&language=en

It depends on your exact use case how the details need to be filled. 
E.g. you could check for a 'type' change to private, in combination with a check on equality between the email address on custom object and account. If they are equal, set the Account level field to empty.

Comment: It should also be noted that this will only work if the relationship between the two objects is a Master-Detail relationship. There are also additional caveats. Not all Standard Object -> Custom Object Master-Detail relationships, and very few Standard Object -> Standard Object Master-Detail relationships, support cross-object field updates. More exact details are provided in the link to the documentation given in the answer.